# Finding $\theta$ that maximizes $\frac{u^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}-\frac{2Fu^2\sin^2(\theta)}{mg^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, physics

I am trying to solve a physics problem to do with finding the ideal angle for the maximum range, $x$, of a projectile, with air resistance taken into consideration ($\therefore \theta \neq 45^{\circ}$).

Here is the final equation I have arrived at:

$$x =\frac{u^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}-\frac{2Fu^2\sin^2(\theta)}{mg^2}$$

How would I find the angle $\theta$ that results in the greatest possible value of $x$, assuming that the values of $u$, $g$, $F$, and $m$ are known constants?

Comment: You've tagged this with `algebra-precalculus`. Is calculus allowed?

Comment: Yes, calculus is allowed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \frac{u^2}{g}$ and $\beta = \frac{2Fu^2}{mg^2}$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d x}{d \theta}
=
2\alpha\cos(2\theta)
-
2
\beta
 \sin \theta \cos \theta = 0
\end{equation}
But $\sin 2\theta =2 \sin \theta \cos \theta $, hence arranging we get
$$\tan 2 \theta = \frac{2\alpha}{\beta}$$
Can you continue?